# When creating a new Stack Exchange account it says display name is optional, but it's not

Tags: bug, status-norepro, stack-exchange-openid, sign-up

When signing up for a new Stack Exchange account (e.g. on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/users/login#create-account)), it says the user name is optional:

> [image]

I tried to sign up without entering a name, and it did not work.

Comment: Sorry but I could not reproduce. I filled email and password, clicked the button and it worked just fine. Can you please post the full error message you got or better yet, a screenshot?

Comment: Anyway it's not really relevant, the whole design is about to change soon, try to sign up here on Meta and see the new design.

Comment: I am a (responsible) newbie in one of forums.  I thought I encountered a bug that nobody noticed.  But if the design is about to change, there is really no point to fix it.